# How to implement autocorrelation (matched filter) in hardware?

Tags: signal-processing, hardware

I have an understanding of how to implement autocorrelation via the means of software, but after an extensive search on the internet I could not find how to implement it with hardware/electronics. In some places, it was suggested to use a correlator.

Comment: FPGA or analog implementation?

Comment: Analog, but i would also like to explore FPGA solutions  @BrianCarlton

Comment: What kind of signal are you trying to match? Or might it vary? I don't think a general analog matched filter is possible (I might be wrong) but you can match a sinusoid by using a mixer or analog multiplier. In an FPGA, you can sample, then feed the digital data through a series of N registers. Then you can trivially compute the correlation over those N registers every sample period (assuming you have N multipliers).

Comment: square pulses to begin, and i would like to extend it to chirp pulses and audio signal.

Comment: A: With great difficuty. | Look at the functions implemented by the software. You must provide a hardware "block" for each component in the core program. In software a routine may get used multiple times with variables providing the related data for a series of "blocks". In hardware you either provide eack block physically or must have an equivalent means ("memory") to save and retrieve data for each "block". Commercial products I encountered some while ago used a long string of stages with "memory" per stage.

Comment: Googling "analog matched filter" does find some proposed implementations, e.g. http://www.jpier.org/PIERB/pierb05/16.08022406.pdf or http://www.wseas.us/e-library/conferences/crete2002/papers/444-739.pdf but they seem mostly academic. The latter one was implemented as an ASIC though.

Comment: Also I found a FPAA implementation http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/SIITME.2010.5653267 For FPGA they're often found in SDRs (software defined radios), so you may even have luck getting the code from an opencore of that kind.

Comment: Square pulses could be amenable to a digital implementation. Basically, for each bit that equals the expected bit, you increase your correlation sum by 1. Somehow you would have to stay "in sync" with the transmitter.